# Why does Word chain separate numbered lists together when it saves?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have a Word 2010 file which is basically like this

```
Blah blah blah.
1. Alpha.
2. Beta.
3. Gamma.
Blah blah blah.
```

I mail merge it with an Excel sheet and everything looks fine, but when I save it and load it again, the second instance will be numbered 4, 5, 6, instead of 1, 2, 3, and subsequent instances also have increasing numbers.

Is this a bug or a mysterious feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft was aware of this issue in Word 2000 and provided workarounds.  It is unclear why the issue has not since been fixed.

> [WD2000: Lists Are Numbered Incorrectly in Catalog Mail Merge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/251234)
>
> To work around this problem, use either of the following methods.
>
> Method 1: Restart Numbering in Each Numbered List After Merging 
>   ...
>   Method 2: Manually Number List

Alternatively, call the VBA function [ActiveDocument.ConvertNumbersToText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838874(v=office.14).aspx) before merging to convert the automatic numbering to text.  Without automatic numbering, there is no sequence to continue.